# Book about a girl escaping beyond her kingdom walls

Tags: story-identification, books, novel

I don't remember much since it was so long ago but there was this girl who lived in a kingdom surrounded by walls. Beyond those walls laid a deserted land of sand which had no life. She escapes and goes beyond the walls for some reason and is met with this biker gang (?) where she meets the love interest.

A specific piece of information I remember is that he has this necklace that we later find out his mother made for him (she's an alchemist) and it would change if he met his one true love.

She tags along with them, gets dropped off at this town, meets a fake love interest, gets tricked, gets rescued, and I think somewhere in the book series she found a spaceship?

Comment: I am assuming that, as a book, this is a text novel, not a manga?

Comment: Yep, this is a book, I think it's part of a trilogy

Comment: In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: I read this book about 5 years ago, I don't know when it might have been published but I'm thinking around 2015-2019